# Getting value from table with max key

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with two columns:

```
UserId (auto int)
Email(Nvarchar)
```

I want to retrieve the email that was last inserted on table.

I've tried some options, but nothing seems to be working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps simply:

```
SELECT TOP 1 email FROM dbo.Table ORDER BY UserId DESC
```

or

```
SELECT UserId, Email
FROM dbo.Table
WHERE UserId = (SELECT MAX(UserId) FROM dbo.Table)
```

However, it's not good practise to abuse a primary-key column for information like "last inserted". Add a datetime column for this.

You could also use the `ROW_NUMBER` function:

```
WITH x  AS (
    SELECT UserId, Email,
        rn = Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY UserId DESC) 
    FROM   dbo.table) 
SELECT UserId, Email
FROM   x 
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Comment: Tim Schmelter Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Tim Schmelter thanks for the answer. I've already tried it and nothing seems to be working.
I only want the email referring to that UserId, to store in a variable.
I'm using this in a website creation and trying to get the last email stored on db to send a email to that person.

Can you understand?

Comment: @user2017968: Does my sql work in sql-server management studio? I assume that the problem is somewhere else. If you only want the eamil-column, have you changed my query to `SELECT Email ...` instead of `SELECT UserId, Email ...` instead?

Comment: Yes, but the error pressists. So i need to assume that the error is somewhere else?

Comment: I done the first suggestion of the edited answer, and it works. The error now is that the value nedds to be a string type and its not. Any way, the first problem is solved, so, thank you very much for the help.